# How can I format a value as money (ex. 123,456.50) in a textbox while typing?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

I want to format the contents of my textbox while typing.
I know that I can do this in `LostFocus` event, but I want it to be done while I am typing. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to rig this up yourself, consider using a control that's specifically designed to handle formatted input. **Specifically, you need the [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) control**, which is an enhanced version of the existing textbox that allows you to set a "mask" used to distinguish between valid and invalid input. The user even gets visual feedback as they type.

You'll need to set the [`Mask` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) to tell the control how you want its contents to be formatted. All of the possible values are shown in the linked documentation. To display money, you would use something like: `$999,999.00`, which represents a currency value in the range of 0 to 999999. The neat part is that the currency, thousandth, and decimal characters are automatically replaced at run-time with their culture-specific equivalents, making it much easier to write international software.

Comment: If I used MaskedTextBox, wat if the user inputs 1,000.00 and my MaskedtextBox is set as 1,000,000.00..

Comment: @jamie: That's perfectly allowable, as long as you set the `Mask` property correctly. You wouldn't set it to `1,000,000.00` because the `0` specifies a *required* digit between 0 and 9. Instead, you would use a `9` (like in my example), which means a digit or space is *optional* there. That way, the user could always enter a number less than your maximum place value.

Comment: i did your suggestion, i set the maskedtextbox property to 999,999.00. but if i typed in 1000 in the masked textbox i get a result that looks like this 100,0__.__, i want the result to look like this 1,000.00 how can i do that?

Comment: Code Gray, would you please give me some example codes for this problem.. thank you

Comment: @jamie: Yeah, that's how the masked textbox will look by default. If you want the numbers to "push in" from the right like a pocket calculator, you can subclass the control and modify it's behavior. A sample is provided [here on MSDN blogs.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/irenak/archive/2006/03/21/556434.aspx). You're not going to get off without writing some code if you want to modify the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TBItemValor_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TBItemValor.KeyPress
        If (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = False AndAlso Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False AndAlso Char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) = False) OrElse Not IsNumeric(Me.TBItemValor.Text & e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Dim strCurrency As String = ""
Dim acceptableKey As Boolean = False

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If (e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) OrElse (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 And e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) OrElse e.KeyCode = Keys.Back Then
            acceptableKey = True
        Else
            acceptableKey = False
        End If
    End Sub

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    ' Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
    If acceptableKey = False Then
        ' Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
        e.Handled = True
        Return
    Else
        If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back) Then
            If strCurrency.Length > 0 Then
                strCurrency = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 1)
            End If
        Else
            strCurrency = strCurrency & e.KeyChar
        End If

        If strCurrency.Length = 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text = ""
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 1 Then
            TextBox1.Text = "0.0" & strCurrency
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length = 2 Then
            TextBox1.Text = "0." & strCurrency
        ElseIf strCurrency.Length > 2 Then
            TextBox1.Text = strCurrency.Substring(0, strCurrency.Length - 2) & "." & strCurrency.Substring(strCurrency.Length - 2)
        End If
        TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)

    End If
```

e.Handled = True
    End Sub

@stynx